# Performance of ExpanderView is bad on expanding (XAML + UWP)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander, uwp

I'm building an UWP app that uses the a ported version of the ExpanderView of WPF ([ExpanderRT on Codeplex](https://expanderview.codeplex.com/)), I use a ListBox to show multiple ExpanderViews depending on my the data from my ViewModel. I'm facing a performance issue on expanding an ExpanderView with many items. As you can see in the GIF the first parent expands very slowly and takes some time to show all the child items. If a parent has not as many childs the animation is quite smooth.

Has anyone experience with this control and can help me to make the expanding faster?

This is my XAML Code:

```
        <Grid>
    <ListBox Name="listbox">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Parent">
                <controls:ExpanderControl
                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Childs}"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}" 
                    ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomExpanderTemplate}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}"
                    NonExpandableHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomNonExpandableHeaderTemplate}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This code is from the Model

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<Subcategory> Childs{ get; set; }
}
```

[image: Slow expanding]

Comment: That is NOT a performance issue... And it looks smooth enough to me. The animation simply has a cascading effect that animates items one after another by a short delay. If you don't want this behaviour, you need to go find the animation code and change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin XL pointed me in the right direction!
This behaviour is caused by the animation of the ExpanderView.

In the class `ExpanderControl.cs` there are these properties to control the animation of the collapsing and expanding process.

```
    private const int KeyTimeStep = 35;
    private const int InitialKeyTime = 225;
    private const int FinalKeyTime = 250;
```

Decreasing the value of the KeyTimeStep leads to a faster expanding and collapsing animation.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello @JustinXL , I tried this in the UWP Win-10 (Universal App) but didn't work... can you plz help me. I need the exact control with exact look and animation please.

Comment: @ZiaUrRahman I created a UWP optimized version of the control. You can find it on GitHub https://github.com/nor0x/UWP_Expander